# Internet not working (partially) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, internet

I've recently gotten a new internet connection (fiber connection) with WiFi. I've had it set up properly and it works with all other devices I own (two android phones, one Windows 8.1 laptop), but it doesn't seem to be working with Ubuntu.

My laptop shows that it's connected to the network in question, but I've tried Firefox but it gives me a 'server not found' page. I tried to update it through software updater, and it doesn't seem to connect either. BUT Transmission torrent client can connect and is working.

Looking for some help.

entering ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com yields:

> ping: unknown host www.ubuntu.com

entering ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com yields:

> PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=38.9 ms
>   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=36.3 ms
>   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=38.4 ms
>
> --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
>   3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.350/37.921/38.955/1.129 ms

Comment: You have a DNS problem.

Comment: Oh. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and change the first: nameserver to `nameserver 8.8.8.8` save and exit and try to ping www.google.com again. If that works you need to fix your DHCP to send this as DNS (if you are using DHCP and not static).

If you are using static ip, you have to set the following parameter in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The '8.8.8.8' is a name server provided by google. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS   DNS is what translates the human-readable machine name like www.ubuntu.com into the Internet-functional 32bit (for IPv4) number 91.189.89.115. You need this whenever you contact the Internet. And it is frequently done also with every web page that needs to add additional information for JavaScript or Style sheets from other servers than the one you are contacting.

The 38.4ms to 8.8.8.8 is the time you need for each request. This is just find while you are now testing, but eventually you may just set it to the IP number of your modem. That has a DNS server built-in and knows how to contact the DNS of your Internet provider. This replies in fractions of milliseconds for all that is has already cached from earlier requests. This will help a lot to fully enjoy your fibre connection. Just to explain, if you have a 100Mbit/s connect, then in 38.4ms you transfer 3.84Mbit of data, which may be more than the content of the web site you downloaded.